# Excluding internal headers from framework umbrella header

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, clang

While trying to begin using Swift in a framework (including turning on module support), I started getting messages like this:

```
[snip]/<module-includes>:1:1: Umbrella header for module 'PressKit' does not include header 'NPKBaseAppearance.h'
```

The headers in question (there are about ten of them) are not listed in PressKit.h, but with good reason—they include internal or rarely-used classes and categories that I don't want to expose to most users of my framework. (Some of them I'd like to expose in select places; others should never be exposed.)

Marking the headers as private doesn't seem to help. This is a warning in my framework's project, but an error in each target using the framework, so I can't just ignore the problem.

Obviously I can add these headers to my umbrella header, but I don't want to. Am I violating some rule of framework design when using modules? What's the recommended way to handle this sort of situation?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the recommended way to handle this sort of situation?

Not sure if it's the recommended way, but here's how I got rid of that warning:

1. I've created a private module map that lists all internal headers and placed it in the root folder of my framework project, as `module.private.modulemap`:

   ```
   framework module PressKit_Private {
       header "NPKBaseAppearance.h"
       export *
   }
   ```
2. I have configured Xcode to use that module map

[image: Screenshot]

3. I configured Xcode to treat those internal headers as private headers. That will cause Xcode to place them in `PressKit.framework/PrivateHeaders` when creating the framework.

[image: Screenshot]

Now, when importing the `PressKit` module in Swift or Objective-C, the functions from the headers from the private module map are not available. One needs to import `PressKit_Private` to make them available.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already solved this issue yourself but did you try to exclude the headers you don't want to export in a custom .modulemap file?

Have a look at:
[Clang 3.7 documentation - Modules](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#header-declaration)