# Swift and Objective-C framework exposes its internals

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, clang

I’m trying to add Swift to an existing Objective-C framework that has public, private and project files. In order for Swift to access the project files, I added a modulemap that defines a new module (e.g. `MyFramework_Internal`) by including all the project headers as explained here: http://nsomar.com/project-and-private-headers-in-a-swift-and-objective-c-framework/

That setup is sort of working but one thing I was surprised to see is that now a client can access the internal classes by importing `MyFramework_Internal` (i.e. `@import MyFramework_Internal`). Is there a way to hide the module since it's only needed by the framework itself?
The modulemap looks like this now:

```
module MyFramework_Internal {  
   header "Folder1/Baz.h"  
   header "Folder1/Folder2/Bar.h"  
   export *
}
```

Comment: For public framework assembly you can create different target, post-process assembled framework by copying different module map into your module, which will not expose modules that are private.

Comment: Also, you can try to add a private module map `module.private.modulemap` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265339/private-module-map-for-a-framework

Answer (score 2):

The modulemap file is intended for Objective-C and Objective-C doesn't have the concept of `internal`. It only knows public (what's declared in the header files), and private (what's declared only in the implementation files).

Thus, anything that ends up in a modulemap file will be publicly available.