# Hide an Objective-C initializer (or method) from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization

I have a *Framework* with has one *Objective-C* class with one designated initializer which takes two `NSArray`s. Inside the *Framework*, I have defined a *Swift* extension which provides an extra initializer which takes an array of tuples instead of the two arrays.

When importing the *Framework* eternally, is it possible to hide the original *Objective-C* initializer from *Swift* (so only the initializer taking the array of tuples can be used) but keep it available when using the *Framework* from *Objective-C* code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by @mattt:

> Use the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` macro (available only on *Xcode 7* and up).

Answer (score 2):

You could:

YourApp-Brindging-Header.h

```
#define __BRIDGING__
#import "YourObjCObject.h"
#undef __BRIDGING__
```

YourObjCObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface YourObjCObject : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger count;

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)ary1 Array2:(NSArray *)ary2 NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#ifdef __BRIDGING__
NS_UNAVAILABLE
#endif
;
@end
```

Comment: BTW, if you hide *designated initializer* from Swift, how do you implement *convenience intializer* in Swift extension?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of my problem. I want to use it on my own convenience initializer, but I want to hide it elsewhere. If that's not possible, I can reimplement the *designated initializer* from Swift anew. Also, an additional issue, this is inside a Framework, which doesn't have a bridging header (as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)). Can my requested behaviour be achieved for the users of the framework?

Comment: Or in other words, can *usage from Swift* be detected from the preprocessor macro without manually defining `__BRIDGING__ ` as in your solution?

Comment: So, this QA might help you? [How to import private framework headers in a Swift framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28746214/3804019).

Comment: Thanks, that's promising! However, I cannot still see a way to do what I wanted from outside the *Framework*: have the *Obj-C* initializer available from *Obj-C*, but have only the *Swift* initializer available from *Swift*. I have updated the question to reflect this. I'll read the [Clang Modules documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html), to see if I can find anything suitable.