# How to detect if an Objective-C header is being used/compiled from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, c-preprocessor

Is there any preprocessor macro that tells the *Objective-C* compiler that the header is being included from *Swift* (inside a *Framework*)? I want to conditionally make available some methods to *Objective-C*, but not to *Swift*.

This is a follow-on to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084223/hide-an-objective-c-initializer-or-method-from-swift).

Comment: Use the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` macro.

Comment: Is this macro *iOS 9* only?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be new in *Xcode 7*. If you add an answer with this info, I'll accept it. You can answer to both questions, as the same solution applies to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @mattt:

> Use the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` macro (available only on *Xcode 7* and up).

Answer (score 0):

Here a nice explanation about some macro's in objc to work with swift.

https://academy.realm.io/posts/altconf-nikita-lutsenko-objc-swift-interoperability/

Like mentioned you have the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` but also `NS_SWIFT_NAME` for example which allows you to change the signature of your functions for swift.