# How to make a Swift framework submodule really private?

Tags: swift, module, frameworks, cocoapods, access-control

I've found another question which brings more details regarding the problem and possible solutions. It seems like there is a known bug which is a subject for future improvements.

[Objective C classes within an iOS Swift-based dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535972/objective-c-classes-within-an-ios-swift-based-dynamic-framework)

I'm developing a framework in Swift and I'm using some Objective-C code inside the framework. So far my module map looks like this:

```
framework module MyModule {
    umbrella header "MyModule-umbrella.h"

    export *

    explicit module Private {
        header "MyTools.h"
    }
}
```

My concern is that all the APIs from `MyTools.h` are visible from outside the framework: for example, if you install the framework using Cocoapods, then you `import MyModule` into your application (**not MyModule.Private**), you are able to access `MyTools.h` which is not desirable and redundant. Is there any way to make MyTools invisible from outside the framework?

PS. I use Cocoapods to distribute the framework, here is my podspec (the most significant part):

```
s.module_map    = 'Pod/MyModule.modulemap'
s.frameworks    = 'CoreData', 'CoreTelephony', 'SystemConfiguration'
s.resources     = 'Pod/Classes/MessageStorage/*.xcdatamodeld'
s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
s.private_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/MyTools/**/*.h'
s.source_files  = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

PSS. My umbrella header does not import `MyTools.h`

PSSS. Just tried to exclude the header from the main module:

```
framework module MyModule {
    umbrella header "MyModule-umbrella.h"

    export *
    exclude header "MyTools.h"

    explicit module Private {
        header "MyTools.h"
    }
}
```

No luck.

Comment: Have you tried to `exclude` private header from module?

Comment: @user28434 You mean in the module map? Just tried it. Doesn't help.

Comment: Can you try again, but without `explicit module` at all?

Comment: @user28434 If I remove the module declaration how would I use the objective-c sources from the swift framework then?

Comment: Remove just `explicit module Private` declaration, and leave rest as it is now.

Comment: @user28434 I tried it earlier. Doesn't solve the problem, and this is obvious to me.

Comment: Sorry for the sidebar: what exactly does the keyword `explicit` do?

Answer (score 3):

I found another question which brings more details regarding the problem and possible solutions (which don't work though). It seems like there is a known bug which is a subject for future improvements.

[Objective C classes within an iOS Swift-based dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535972/objective-c-classes-within-an-ios-swift-based-dynamic-framework)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problems recently. **The quick answer is you can't :)** Even if you declare "private" modulemap, it can be always imported by your framework users. Please note, that usually, it is not a concern, especially with open source. You just say "this is an internal module, don't use it".

**But (there is always but) - you can have behavior, that effectively works the same** - allows you to use your Objective-C classes withing same framework target, without making them public. It works in closed source setup, I'm not 100% sure how would it behave with pods.

The case a bit too complex to paste everything here. I'm adding a link to my article about the topic, maybe it will help you. But speaking honestly - it might be a bit of overhead in your setup.

[Creating Swift framework with private Objective-C members. The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly](https://medium.com/@amichnia_31596/creating-swift-framework-with-private-objective-c-members-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-4d726386644b)

[Github example project](https://github.com/amichnia/Swift-framework-with-private-ObjC-example)

Comment: I saw your blog posts. Can you tell me if it is possible to do optional frameworks with swift and #if canImport?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods