# Type extensions from a framework's dependency available in app

Tags: swift, frameworks

OK... this is difficult to explain (and to come up with a title for) but I'll try my best.

We first discovered this when using Carthage to import stuff but setting up a sample project in Xcode (without using Carthage) it seems to have done the same thing.

First, here's a screenshot of the sample project we set up...

[image]

The have a target **Test20000** and it has a dependency **A**.

The **A** framework then has a dependency on **B**.

### Important

The **Test20000** app does *NOT* add **B** as a direct dependency.

### The frameworks

In **B** there is a struct like...

```
import Foundation

public struct BType {
    public let value = "Hello, B!"
}
```

In **A** there is a file like...

```
import Foundation
import B

public struct AType {
    public let value = "Hello, A!"

    public func doAThing() {
        print(BType().value)
    }
}
```

### The App

Now in the **Test20000** app we do something like...

```
import Foundation
import A

struct TestType {
    func doSomething() {
        let aType = AType()

        print(aType.value)
        aType.doAThing()
    }
}
```

This works as expected. It prints...

> Hello, A!
>   Hello, B!

If I change the function to something like this...

```
import Foundation
import A

struct TestType {
    func doSomething() {
        let bType = BType()

        print(bType.value)
    }
}
```

Then this doesn't compile as **B** is not imported and so `BType` can't be accessed.

### The catch!

However! If you declare an extension in **B** something like...

```
extension String {
    func doAThingInB() {
        print(self)
    }
}
```

Then now... without any changes to the imports and the dependencies, I can now change my app code to...

```
import Foundation
import A

struct TestType {
    func doSomething() {
        "Hello, bug!".doAThingInB()
    }
}
```

And this will print out as though the extension is public to the actual App. It sort of "bunny hops" from B, over A and into the app.

I feel like this shouldn't happen at all.

We can't find a way to turn this off or to stop this happening.

Is this a bug?

Is there something we need to do to stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to make use of [private module maps](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#private-module-map-files) to hide the inner framework from being visible to the users of `A`, but had no luck with it. Could be related to [[SR-2896] Private modulemaps do no work properly](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2896).

I guess this is the expected behaviour right now. There are multiple proposals on swift.org forums to implement something like you want, for example [Namespaces x submodules](https://forums.swift.org/t/namespaces-x-submodules/11673/56) or a more relevant one [@_exported and fixing import visibility](https://forums.swift.org/t/exported-and-fixing-import-visibility/9415/52).

Relevant parts from the last one:

> Today’s Swift is designed more like Java or C# or Python, in that if you import Bar in the implementation of Foo it doesn’t affect clients who import Foo. Or, well, it doesn’t make the top-level names of Bar visible to clients who import Foo.
>
> 1. You still need Bar around, because the compiler doesn’t track whether you’ve used one of its types in Foo’s public interface. (That’s the previous section.)
> 2. Extensions in Bar are still made visible to clients who import Foo, because the compiler doesn’t distinguish where extensions come from today.
> 3. Operator declarations in Bar are still made visible to clients who import Foo, because the compiler finds operators in a different way than it finds everything else at the top level.

And from one of the last messages:

> the general outcome of this discussion is that it's probably not worth doing anything clever for Swift vNext: just add "implementation-only import" and maybe "exported import" and leave the rest alone for now.

I'd be happy to know if there is a workaround for this, but it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535972/objective-c-classes-within-an-ios-swift-based-dynamic-framework) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571649/how-to-make-a-swift-framework-submodule-really-private) there is none.

Answer (score 1):

OK... so response from the Swift team...

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9913

This is something they have known about for a while. And they are not looking to fix it any time soon.

So, yes, it's a bug. 
But, no, there isn't any way to fix it.

I guess fixing it would cause more issues than it would fix in terms of breaking changes.